# Let $U$ be a vector space, and let $V$ and $W$ be two subspaces. Prove...

Tags: vector-spaces

**Let $U$ be a vector space, and let $V$ and $W$ be two subspaces. Prove that 
$$
V \cap W=\{\boldsymbol{u} \in U | \boldsymbol{u} \in V \text { og } \boldsymbol{u} \in W\} \subset U
$$
and 
$$
V+W=\{\boldsymbol{v}+\boldsymbol{w} \in U | \boldsymbol{v} \in V \text { og } \boldsymbol{w} \in W\} \subset U
$$
are two subspaces**

**My answer**

For  $V \cap W$

- $\mathbf{0} \in U \implies \mathbf{0} \in V \wedge \mathbf{0} \in W \implies \mathbf{0} \in V \cap W$.
- $
  \underline{u}+\underline{v} \in V \wedge \underline{u}+\underline{v} \in W \Rightarrow \underline{u}+\underline{v} \in V \cap V
  $
- $
  \underline{u} \cdot a \in V \wedge \underline{u} \cdot a \in W \Rightarrow \underline{u} \cdot a \in V \cap W
  $

$V+W$:

Not sure what to do... I do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

$$v_i\in V\;,\;\;w_i\in W\;,\;\;i=1,2\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb F:=\text{ the scalars field}\;\implies$$

$$(v_1+w_1)+(v_2+w_2)=(v_1+v_2)+(w_1+w_2)\in V+W$$

$$k(v_1+w_1)=kv_1+kw_2\in V+W$$